# Auto-response Email is forward back into Salesforce and creating a New Case

Tags: email2case

When a customer send an email to my contact center, email-to-case, an auto-response email is send to the customer. The issue is that this auto-response email is being sent back to Salesforce and creating a new case. What should I do to manage this issue?

Comment: What is the reason Salesforce email is coming back? Is it happening to every user or in some specific cases?

Comment: Shailesh Patil , I've create a workflow rule to send an email notification for incoming emails (email2case). It seems like when this email notification is sent to helpcenter.com, somehow forwards it back into Salesforce creating a new case.

Comment: did you add the `{!Case.ThreadID}` merge field into your workflow's email alert's email template?

Comment: Yes! In the subject and in the body email. The problem is that somehow, multiple emails are sent out from Salesforce when a case is coming into salesforce (email2case or web2case)